# How to say ${f : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}}$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, notation, analytic-geometry

I've googled like a nut trying to get an explanation for the following notation:

${f : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}}$

As I read it: "the function $f$ that maps from the Cartesian product of vector V and V to a real number", i.e. the inner product of a vector space or dot product.

I'd appreciate confirmation on my assumption on how to read the notation.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't have to be an inner product, but inner products do have this form.

Comment: "eff, from vee cross vee to ar"

Comment: "i.e." stands for "id est", which literally means "it is", but is understood as "that is";  I think you mean "e.g.", which stands for "exempli gratia", and means "for example".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You're absolutely correct. I'm well-aware off and quite picky about the difference of the two myself, so thank you for noticing!

Comment: @DonThousand Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: So, perhaps you should correct it, then?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Absolutely not =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simply means that $f$ is a function from the Cartesian product of $V$ by itself into the set $\Bbb R$ of real numbers. It doesn't have to be an inner product. You could have, say, $V=\Bbb R$ and $f(x,y)=xe^{x+\cos(y)}-y$.

Comment: Very much appreciated! I realized that I did not specify any group notation regarding $V$ prior to the function notation, so thank you for pointing out the fact that $V$ does not have to be anything but a set